# Post falsy value with angular resource

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I'm trying to post the scalar value 0 with angular resource, e.g.

```
myResource.save({}, 0, onSuccess, onError};
```

This gives a HTTP 400 error for a POST attempt with empty body.

Looking into the angular sources I see that my post data ultimately becomes the argument to the constructor of Resource, which looks like

```
  function Resource(value){
    shallowClearAndCopy(value || {}, this);
  }
```

So it seems all falsy values will be replaced by an empty object and thus cannot be posted. Is this by design (and then: which part of the documentation did I miss?) or a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of `$resource` is best illustrated when the instance methods are used instead of the class methods. Take [this example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource#example) from the docs:

```
 var CreditCard = $resource('/user/:userId/card/:cardId',
  {userId:123, cardId:'@id'}, {
   charge: {method:'POST', params:{charge:true}}
  });
 ...
 var newCard = new CreditCard({number:'0123'});
 newCard.name = "Mike Smith";
 newCard.$save();
```

Essentially `newCard` is just a plain object representing a model, but enriched with some functionality. `$resource` provides a layer of abstraction. It's an implementation of the [Active Record Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record).

That said, if you want to post a single scalar value, then chances are that you are dealing with a service rather than a resource. In that case it's somewhat obvious that `$resource` (sic!) isn't the right choice.

Comment: This is a point of view I really didn't consider before, so thank you for sharing it. Although you do not explicitly answer my question I guess you favour "it's by design"? However, I'm not (yet) completely convinced. The docs claim that $resource "lets you interact with RESTful server-side data sources", and IMHO there are resources (in the RESTful meaning) whose data can be very well represented by a scalar. And if it was really by design it should only work with objects. Accepting 1 but failing on 0 is not what I'd call an intuitive API.

Comment: @Matthias I've shortened my answer before posting it. Before that I mentioned that a resource can indeed be represented by a single value, but that' a very rare case. You are right that accepting `1` is not very intuitive. I bet `value || {}` is just a sloppy way of saying "if there is no value (=object) take an empty object". Although sloppy it's ok in this case because resources to be used with `$resource` are supposed to be objects. So, yes, it's by design. Using `new Number(0)` instead of just `0` should work.